# Diesel truck at 40Mph huge "stall" and then kick

Tags: chevrolet, diesel, rpm, acceleration, silverado

So I have an 01 Chevy Silverado and i have a little strip that i like to see how fast my truck can go 0-60. The problem is that when I'm accelerating, at around 40mph my truck "stalls"(like im pushing down on the gas, I can see my rpms stay the same but my truck dosent accelerate) its almost like it isn't getting enough fuel. My truck is tuned by Bully Dog and I thought it was because of the defuel settings but I turned them off and the problem still persists. Anyway, after about 4-5 seconds of this happening, my truck finally "kicks" into gear and accelerates normally. Sometimes, I can pump the gas slightly and get that time down to 3 seconds but its still there.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest you have a problem with the transmission ... that has the Allison in it, right?

Comment: That is correct. My truck has 300K miles on it. The transmission was rebuilt at 200K @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦

Comment: sounds like a tranny problem. when it kicks what does the rpms do

Comment: lf you are asking what my rpms do when I accelerate, it shifts like a normal truck until it reaches 45mph (which is around 3000rpms) and then it feels like the truck wants to shift but it does not. the Rpms either stay at the point where it started to act up or go down. @agent provocateur